How to Silence Excel Circular Reference That Will Never Occur?
=IF(AND(CELL("row")=ROW(), CELL("col")<>COLUMN()), NOW(), [@Updated])

I have a column for the time the row was updated using this formula. It works perfectly. [@Updated] references its own cell so that it doesn't change when other rows are updated. Excel thinks it is a circular reference and gives the annoying prompt every time you open the worksheet. This formula cannot be circular by design.
I cannot expect everyone in my company to enable iterative calculations in Excel, so that is not a solution.
I cannot use VBA instead of this formula because that clears the undo history.
Any ideas?

If Excel tell you a function is circular, then it refers to itself and is circular. What is this supposed to accomplish? Maybe some sample data, and the expected result would be useful here. If the condition for the circular reference cannot happen why even include it?

Try using OFFSET() and reference an adjacent cell but use arguments to  reference the formula cell itself.

What is the name of the table column in which this cell appears?  Because, if this is in the column "updated", then this formula is a circular reference: it will reference itself any time you are on a different row, or you have the cell itself highlighted.  And, indeed your statement “[@Updated] references its own cell so that it doesn't change when other rows are updated” seems to suggest that this is exactly what is happening.  That "referencing its own cell" that you mention is what we call a "Circular Reference".

I agree that this is the technical definition of a circular reference, but it will never reiterate so the error/warning is meaningless to me and just an annoyance. There should be an ITERATE() function or at least a file Iterative Calculations setting instead of forcing it into application options.

If you have access to LAMBDA() may be you can use it to do a recursive LAMBDA() to override the circular reference as well as can avoid the volatile functions, lately I have been trying to come up with this, but not yet found success. However you can research on this topic, not sure if anyone has posted yet over here. BTW the dv is not from my end.

If it won't occur, can you simply point it any other location on the sheet or make it blank with ""?

@Operations As I have pointed out, it does iterate.  The iteration is just "f(x)=x", so it returns the same result.  It's a circular reference.  It returns itself.  The only way for it to never reiterate would be for you to only have one row in the table, and then to lock both the formula cell, and every other cell that is not on the same row, and then Protect the worksheet and workbook so that you can never select a cell that is not unlocked.  It doesn't matter how often you repeat saying "it will never reiterate", because it does and is reiterating.

@Chronocidal I was saying that the value will not iterate indefinitely. The cell will not change, breaking any circular behavior.

@Operations Nope.  It still iterates infinitely, it's just that the output matches the input: like I said, it's a function of f(x)=x.  That's still a circle, just one that isn't going anywhere.
